# filesaver Installation give compilation error in angular CLI

Tags: angular

When I install FileSaver `npm install file-saver, npm install @types/file-saver)` my angular CLI gives compilation error "multi file loader error", can't even load Jquery and any other js files in angular.cli.json. If I remove FileSaver from package.json. everything works fine

Comment: Can you please provide the package.json to see versions and packages?

Comment: Hi thanks, could not get over from this error. I added Filesaver.js  directly without adding it in package.json. It is working now